# Weblogic Ear deployment fails to inject entity manager

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ear

The issue I am currently experiencing is that my entityManager fails to be injected during the execution of a web application deployed within an ear.

The ear is setup as follows:

> /META-INF   -application.xml (EJBJar +
>   WAR)
>   -MANIFEST.MF
>   -weblogic-application.xml (currently just the default one that eclipse
>   generates)
>      /APP-INF
>        -lib
>       -EJBClientJar (interfaces + pojos)
>
> ```
> -other jars
>  -classes
> ```
>
> EJBJar
>     /META-INF
>        -persistence.xml
>    /src
>       -Annotated classes
>     WAR
>   -Service classes

Classes are as follows:
`DAO inside EJBJar`

```
@Stateless(mappedName="AwesomeBean")
public class Awesome implements AwesomeRemote //AwesomeRemote in EJBClientJar
{     
   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager em;   
}


public class AwesomeService   //Inside WAR
{  
    AwesomeRemote = context.lookup (Awesome.path.to.AwesomeRemote)  //Is found
}
```

The call stack is like this:
War -> EJBClientJar -> EJBJar
On the EJB jar the entity manager is null.  Question being how do I ensure that the PersistenceContext gets injected?  The JNDI lookup succeeds on the AwesomeRemote Interface.  The Interface has no annotations on it.

Comment: Try specifying unitName on the PersistenceContext annotation?

Comment: that also fails, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: How do you know it is null? Exception? Can you post it?

Comment: The stack trace occurs on em.myMethodHere();  The entity manager does not get injected.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the fact that you try to inject on POJO class, not on managed component. Could you try to mark it as @Stateless and public and check whether it works?
For simple testing you can also add @WebService annotation and invoke your bean with SoapUI for example.

Comment: Still the same problem, with @Stateless

Comment: Have you modified it to public? Is it registered in JNDI tree?

Comment: it is in the JNDI tree, and it is public.  Changes in original post.  Thanks grabowski

Answer (score 0):

You should read about "packaging" part of ejb specifications.

This structure should be sufficient and work:

```
/
    /lib
        EJBClientJar (interfaces + pojos)
    /META-INF
        persistence.xml
        application.xml
    EJBJar.jar
    WAR.war
```

As some formatting was lost, I'm not sure about what wasn't right in yours.

If this still doesn't work, try removing the only tricky part from above: put all classes from EJBClientJar in root. You the just have the most simple EAR packaging possible, it just will work.

Also, if you don't use your session bean outside a web application, you could use @Local instead of @Remote .